# Малое количество отсечений альфа-беты для минимакса

Tags: c++, алгоритм

В статье на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/146088/) и других источниках показываются большие значения альфа-бета оптимизации для минимакса, более половины вариантов урезается. У меня же совсем не так радужно, отбрасывается только порядка 8% вариантов. Такое в принципе нормально? Игра не классическая; каждый раз есть около 7-ми вариантов ходов. С оптимизацией расчёт ходов выполняется точно так же, как и без него, проверил (то есть, лишних ходов не отрезает). Свой код с [псевдокодом](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Pseudocode) сверил, один к одному:

```
int evaluate(const Node &node, bool myturn, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
    if (depth++ == maxdepth) {
        MmNodesLeaves++;
        return node.examine();// эвристическая оценка
    }
    // результаты возможных ходов из текущего состояния
    SomeContainer<Node> variants = node.availableMovesResults();
    for (auto it = variants.begin(); it != variants.end(); it++) {
        Node child = *it;
        // оценка следующего хода
        int k = evaluate(child, !myturn, depth, alpha, beta);
        // Max или Min уровень основывается на том, чей нынче ход
        if (maximize(myturn)) {
            if (k > best) {
                best = k;
                if (best > alpha) {
                    alpha = best;
                }
                if (alpha > beta) {
                    MmPruningsA++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (k < best) {
                best = k;
                if (best < beta) {
                    beta = best;
                }
                if (alpha > beta) {
                    MmPruningsB++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Начальный вызов:

```
// значения функции оценки = ±1000, alpha и beta с запасом
// game — текущее состояние игры 
evaluate(*game, true, 0, -2047, 2048);
```

Конкретные результаты оценки всегда примерно такие:

> Max depth: 4, Leaves: 105807, alpha-prunings: 214, beta-prunings: 1205

Мне нужно искать ошибку или принять, что оптимизация не столь полезна?

<sub>P.S.: возможно, кто-то обратил внимание, что этот код не возвращает лучшего варианта — он чуть упрощён.</sub>